# How can i searching from Map<String, List<dynamic>> Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, list, search, mapping

i'm try to make Search Bar and Searching from  Map<String, List>
but i got  error like this --> "A value of type 'Iterable<MapEntry<String, List>>'
can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, List>"

//here the function that i try.
Map<String, List> datasource_map = {};

Map<String, List> result = {};
void updateList(String enteredKeyword) {

```
setState(() {
  result = datasource_map.entries.map((e) {
    return MapEntry(
        e.key,
        e.value
            .where(
              (element) => element.foodName!.toLowerCase().contains(
                    enteredKeyword.toLowerCase(),
                  ),
            )
            .toList());
  });
  print("### $result");
});
```

}

[this is my Model of foodCard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEr9u.png)

what should i try ? i am new at flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your datasource_map.entries is a List - calling a map() on it will produce an Iterator - not a Map object.

You should use Map.fromEntries constructor:

```
result = Map.fromEntries(datasource_map.entries.map((e) {
    return MapEntry(
        e.key,
        e.value
            .where(
              (element) => element.foodName!.toLowerCase().contains(
                    enteredKeyword.toLowerCase(),
                  ),
            )
            .toList());
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone! I solved it.

This works:

```
Map<String, List<dynamic>> result = {};

  void updateList(String enteredKeyword) {
    Map<String, List<dynamic>> mapResult = {};

    datasource_map.forEach((key, value) {
      List foodByFilter = value.where((element) {
        return element.foodName
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(_textEditingController.text.toLowerCase().toString());
      }).toList();

      if (foodByFilter.isNotEmpty) mapResult[key] = foodByFilter;
    });

    setState(() {
      result = mapResult;
    });
  }
```